# Document.getElementById in a loop outputs once only

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function that has a first loop that creates a dynamic javascript table.It then outputs the table to a htm. The second loop within it is to call a countdown clock function that outputs to the div tags created in the first loop. For now it only prints out in the first table entry. The second one is blank. How do I solve this?

```
 function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var table;
  var i;
  table=("<table>");
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        table+=("<tr>");
        table+=("<td> Time Left : </td>");
        table+=("<td><div id=\"dday\"></div></td>");
        table+=("<td><div id=\"dhour\"></div></td>");
        table+=("<td><div id=\"dmin\"></div></td>");
        table+=("<td><div id=\"dsec\"></div></td>");
        table+=("</tr>");
    } 
 table+=("</table>");
 document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML=table;
 var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
 var z
 for (z=0;z<y.length;z++)
 { 
    countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min);
 }
}
function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min)
{
    document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML="HH";
    document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML=dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML=dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML=dsec;
}
```

Comment: you can also try y=xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("Product");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An id needs to be unique in the page to work properly. When you use `getElementById`, it will only return one of the elements with that id. (If it could return different elements, it still couldn't guess which one you wanted.)

You can include the counter in the id to make them unique:

```
table += "<td><div id=\"dday" + i + "\"></div></td>";
table += "<td><div id=\"dhour" + i + "\"></div></td>";
table += "<td><div id=\"dmin" + i + "\"></div></td>";
table += "<td><div id=\"dsec" + i + "\"></div></td>";
```

Then you include the counter in the call:

```
countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, z);
```

In the function you use the counter to find the right element:

```
function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i)
{
    document.getElementById('dday' + i).innerHTML = "HH";
    document.getElementById('dhour' + i).innerHTML = dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin' + i).innerHTML = dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec' + i).innerHTML = dsec;
}
```

Note: I don't know where you get the variables `yr`, `m`, `d`, `hr` and `min` that you use in the call, and where you get the variables `dhour`, `dmin` and `dsec` that you use in the function. It seems that you would rather use the parameters in the function, but there is no parameter for seconds.

Working demo (with mocked data, and some variable declarations added):

```js
loadXMLDoc();

function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var table;
  var i;
  table = "<table>";
  var x = [1,2,3];
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td> Time Left : </td>";
        table += "<td><div id=\"dday" + i + "\"></div></td>";
        table += "<td><div id=\"dhour" + i + "\"></div></td>";
        table += "<td><div id=\"dmin" + i + "\"></div></td>";
        table += "<td><div id=\"dsec" + i + "\"></div></td>";
        table += "</tr>";
    } 
 table += "</table>";
 document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML = table;
 var y = [1,2,3];
 var z;
  var yr = 1, m = 2, d = 3, hr = 4, min = 5;
 for (z=0;z<y.length;z++)
 { 
    countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, z);
 }
}
function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i)
{
  var dhour = 1, dmin = 2, dsec = 3;
    document.getElementById('dday' + i).innerHTML="HH";
    document.getElementById('dhour' + i).innerHTML=dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin' + i).innerHTML=dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec' + i).innerHTML=dsec;
}
```

```html
<div id="listinglist"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this method. However, it still doesn't output HH. The variables are declared in the first function. This is what I have done so far. table+="<td><div id=\"dday\"+i+\"></div></td>";

Comment: oops sorry. Now it's saying it cannot detect the id of null

Comment: I've tried to output it on fiddle. Can you help me check it out? https://jsfiddle.net/aup3otz4/

Comment: @JianYA: I just noticed that you changed the variable in the second loop from `i` to `z`. I changed the code to match. I added a working demo above.

Comment: @JianYA: Here's the fiddle with variables added to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aup3otz4/1/

Comment: For some reason when added to my code, it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. It shows my countdown timer, but it outputs the error and the seconds dont subtract until i refresh

Comment: @JianYA: The error message means that `getElementById` returned `null` because it didn't find any element. Check what id you are looking for.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aup3otz4/1/ I've edited the fiddle you made. It's not showing for some reason now. Assuming it works properly, it should output 4 countdown timers. Could you check to see if you can find anything wrong with it? I am not sure why its not working

Comment: @JianYA: If you edited the fiddle, you need to include the URL to the new version for me to see it.

Comment: @JianYA: Removed a trailing `}`, changed script inclusion to "No wrap - in <head>" (so that variables and the function are global), put code in an `onload` event handler, added the `i` parameter to the function and the `getElementById` calls in the function, changed the string to a function in `setTimeout` so that the `i` parameter could be included. https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aup3otz4/3/

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `id` for `dday`. `id` must be unique, no wonder you are getting the same element over and over again when you tried `document.getElementById('dday')`.  Use `class` instead, or make your `id` unique.

If you happen to change it to `class`

JS

```
function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min, i) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('dday')[i].innerHTML = "HH";
}
```

Comment: I tried using class name. I changed the first id to class and in the second function, i changed the getElementById of dday to getElementsByClassName. It doesnt work

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns and array of elements.

Comment: When I use a class, how do i select that class? I don't really know how to handle getElementsByClassName. Is it the same as getElementsById

Comment: You can use like this `document.getElementsByClassName('dday')[0]`. `[0]` is the index, just like a normal array.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('dday')[0].innerHTML = 'HH'`

Comment: It now says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined. Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

for a catching all selectors you can also try

```
   y=xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("Product");
```