# ReactJS is not able to differentiate between elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

Basically, Here I am mapping data coming from backend but when I am trying to get textContent of content of h5 tag through postData function, it only gives textContent of first card element not 2nd and so forth..
Is it has something to do with key while mapping in ReactJS ?
Can anyone tell me where is the problem ?

````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Cards extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      cData:[]
    }
  }

  postData(){
    let ff = document.getElementById('ccc')
    let dd = ff.textContent
    console.log(dd);
    let data = { course: dd}
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/api', data)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
      { this.state.cData.map(el => (
      <div className="card mb-3 jj" key={Math.random()}>
       
        <div className="row g-0">
          <div className="col-md-4">
            
            <img
              src={el.Image}
              alt="..."
              className="img-fluid ii"
            />

            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-sm btn-info btt"
              onClick={this.dropDetails}
            >
              <small>More Details </small>
            </button>
            <a href="/form" >
            <button type="button" className="btn-sm btn-info" **onClick={this.postData}**>
              <small> Book Now </small>
            </button>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-1"> </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="card-body">
              **<h5 className="card-title" id="ccc">{el.Course}</h5>**
              <b> {el.FFS} </b> <br />
              <span className="card-text">
                <small className="text-muted">{el.FPS}</small>
              </span>
              <br /> <br />
              <span>
                By : {el.CP} <br />
                Age : {el.Age} <br />
                {el.TIW} <br />
                {el.ON} | {el.Cen} <br />
                {el.Skills}
              </span>{" "}
              <br /> <br />
    ) )}     );
  }
}```
````

Comment: `.getElementById()` only returns the first element ( `id` is expected to be unique across the document). But you have the data in state already, so why are you querying the DOM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Document.getElementById in a loop outputs once only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297285/document-getelementbyid-in-a-loop-outputs-once-only)

Comment: So, how can I get textContent of h5 tag ? How can I differentiate between the elements that are being rendered by mapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using same id inside your `map`. IDs should be unique in a page.

If you have multiple IDs in a page `getElementById` will return only the first one.

You could change this line

```
<h5 className="card-title" id="ccc">{el.Course}</h5>
```

to

```
<h5 className="card-title ccc" >{el.Course}</h5>
```

and get the elemnts array like

```
let ff = document.querySelectorAll('.ccc');
```

> I don't want to get all the elements at once, I need to differentiate
> between the elements so that I can get the textContent of each h5 tag
> element

```
ff.forEach((element) => {
     console.log(element.textContent); // prints the textContent of each element.
})
```

> I need one textContent per click, as per your solution when I am clicking on one card its showing me the textContent of all the cards
> at once

You need to pass the index to `postData` and get the corresponding node.

Your `map` have a second parameter called index.

```
this.state.cData.map((el,index) => (
```

Pass this index to postData like this

```
onClick={()=>this.postData(index)}
```

Get the corresponding node in `postData` based on the `index`.

```
postData(index){
    let ff = document.querySelectorAll('.ccc');
    const clickedNode = ff[index];

    const clickedNodeTextContent = clickedNode.textContent;
```

Comment: I don't want to get all the elements at once, I need to differentiate between the elements so that I can get the textContent of each h5 tag element

Comment: In my code above you will have an array in `ff`, loop `ff` and in  each iteration you will get a node from which you can get `textContent`. I have updated my anwser with this.  Will that work for you?

Comment: I need one textContent per click, as per your solution when I am clicking on one card its  showing me the textContent of all the cards at once.

Comment: Awesome buddy, Thanks a ton :)